# Amazon S3 Signature

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you create the hex encoded signature in crypto in a nodejs environment?

[image]

Do you just do this like so?

```
const secret = 'mysecret';
const date = yyyymmdd;
const dateKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'AWS4' + secret + ',' + date);
const dateRegionKey = crypto('sha256', dateKey + ',' + 'myregion')
const DateRegionServiceKey = crypto('sha256', dateRegionKey + ',' + 'someservice');
const signingKey = crypto('sha256', DateRegionServiceKey + ',' + 'aws4_request');

const signature = crypo('sha256', signingKey + base64Policy);
```

Comment: `base64Policy`?  So, you're creating a signature for a [browser-based form `POST` upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)?

Answer (score 0):

High level it looks ok. I hope you know that secret is not just a string, it is the secretKey of your IAM User accessKey/secretKey pair.

Any particular reason you want to do it yourself and not use the AWS SDK?

Also look at below for a sample signing implementation (in Java) which works for AWS ElasticSearch. Look at getSignatureKey and calculateSignature methods.

https://github.com/dy10/aws-elasticsearch-query-java/blob/master/src/main/java/dy/aws/es/AWSV4Auth.java

Answer (score 0):

you should use this library https://github.com/mhart/aws4
you need to use `result = aws4.sign({}, { cred from AWS })`

and it returns result.headers that are the headers you need to send in your request